# Azure SQL Databaseのサービスレベル変更について

Tags: azure, sql-azure

Azure SQL DatabaseでDTUベースのサービスレベル「Standard」を使用しています。
DTUが"5"で、データ容量が2GBまでのサービスレベル「Basic」に変更したいのですが、
現在のAzure SQL Databaseの使用済み容量（Azure Portal上で確認）が40MB程度の場合、
変更しても既存のデータベースはそのまま生きますでしょうか。
例えばSSMSなどでの参照は変わらずできるのでしょうか。（速度低下は別として）